# get observable from a subscription

Tags: angular, observable, observer-pattern, subscribe

After doing some experiments, I post the code without my changes, to find the best practice:
I have a function (in service) that subscribes to a result as a BLOB and save it as a content of a file to the local file system  - FileSaver.saveAs(result, );:

```
printAsPDF()
{
   if (<some validator fails>)
   {
      return;
   } 
   let htmlContent = "<html><body>" + <some html content> +"</body></html>";
   //this.GetByteArrayForPDF returns Observable<any> (actually observable of a blob)
   this.GetByteArrayForPDF(htmlContent).subscribe(result => 
   {
      FileSaver.saveAs(result, <file name>); 
   }, error => console.log(error));
}
```

Now, I want that function printAsPDF to return also an observable which indicate whether the save action succeeded or not. 
Currently, the call to that function is being executed from a component:

```
this.<service name>.printAsPDF();
```

I want that component function to subscribe to the observable and check if the saving succeeded or not.
How can I do it taking into consideration that the call to printAsPDF should get an observable(true) depending if FileSaver.saveAs(result, ) was called

Comment: is `FileSaver.saveAs()` async? If so does it utilize something like `Promise` or even an `Observable`? Also what version of RxJS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `subscribe` to a `map` (you'll need to subscribe in your component to make the observable hot of course). You can move the error handler to your component or put it in a `catch` method.

```
return this.GetByteArrayForPDF(htmlContent)
.map(result => 
{
   FileSaver.saveAs(result, <file name>); 
   return true;
})
.catch(error => { 
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.of(false);
});
```

or using pipeable operators (RxJS 5.5+):

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.GetByteArrayForPDF(htmlContent).pipe(
map(result => 
{
   FileSaver.saveAs(result, <file name>); 
   return true;
}),
catchError(error => { 
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.of(false);
}));
```

Comment: You should probably show this in the form of RxJS 5.5+ pipeable operators as well in line with current Angular documentation and versions of RxJS used from tools such as `@angular/cli`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have a feeling I'm about to learn something... since I have no idea what you are talking about :). If you want to just edit my answer that's fine or I'll fix it after looking those up.